# Create search box on Archive Custom post type

Tags: search, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to create a search box on an archive page which shows on Custom post type.

I've followed this guide to implement the search box on the archive page:

http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/template/create-multiple-search-templates-for-custom-post-types/

So I've created a search.php file and I put this code in it:

```
<?
/* Template Name: Search Results */
$search_refer = $_GET["post_type"];
if ($search_refer == 'spec-needs-res') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/template_search_spec_needs.php'); }
else { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/template_search_default.php'); };
?>
```

I've created a template_search_spec_needs.php file and I put this code (loop) in it:

```
  <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'spec-needs-res', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => $s, 'paged' => $paged );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  ?>

        <div class="span4 spec-needs-list-single">
            <div class="spec-needs-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <div class="plus-btn-spec-needs-cont"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="plus-btn-spec-needs">+</button></a></div>
        </div>

  <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
```

I've added this code on the archive-spec-needs-res.php

```
<form id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/" method="get">
        <input id="s" maxlength="150" name="s" size="20" type="text" value="" class="txt" />
        <input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="spec-needs-res" />
        <input id="searchsubmit" class="btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

The process seems to be fine but every time I try searching something I get an empty page, the template is picked up but I have no posts so I never get results.

I've followed the guide step by step, any advice?

UPDATE

I noticed that the search box gives me results just when I do the search but without parameters and obviously, I get all the posts, but once I put a parameter I don't get results anymore so the search box seems to work but I doesn't when I use a keyword to search a custom post.

This is the URL that I get when I do a search with the word "webinar":

http://www.matrix-test.com/edtech3/?s=webinar&post_type=spec-needs-res

Is the URL correct?

I have a custom post type with "Webinar" as a title and another one with "Webinar" as tag and I put webinar somewhere in text as well.

Here the code I used to create the custom post type:

```
/****************************************
 * Add custom taxonomy for Specific Needs *
 ****************************************/

add_action('init', 'spec_needs_cat_register');

function spec_needs_cat_register() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                          => 'Specific Needs Categories',
    'singular_name'                 => 'Specific Needs Category',
    'search_items'                  => 'Search Specific Needs Categories',
    'popular_items'                 => 'Popular Specific Needs Categories',
    'all_items'                     => 'All Specific Needs Categories',
    'parent_item'                   => 'Parent Specific Needs Category',
    'edit_item'                     => 'Edit Specific Needs Category',
    'update_item'                   => 'Update Specific Needs Category',
    'add_new_item'                  => 'Add New Specific Needs Category',
    'new_item_name'                 => 'New Specific Needs Category',
    'separate_items_with_commas'    => 'Separate Specific Needs categories with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'           => 'Add or remove Specific Needs categories',
    'choose_from_most_used'         => 'Choose from most used Specific Needs categories'
    );

$args = array(
    'label'                         => 'Specific Needs Categories',
    'labels'                        => $labels,
    'public'                        => true,
    'hierarchical'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
    'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite'                       => array( 'slug' => 'spec-needs-tax', 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
    'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'spec_needs_cat_register', 'spec-needs-res', $args );
}

/*****************************************
 * Add custom post type for Specific Needs *
 *****************************************/

add_action('init', 'spec_needs_res_register');

function spec_needs_res_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Specific Needs',
        'singular_name' => 'Specific Needs',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Specific Needs',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Specific Needs',
        'new_item' => 'New Specific Needs',
        'view_item' => 'View Specific Needs',
        'search_items' => 'Search Specific Needs',
        'not_found' =>  'Nothing found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'spec-needs-res', 'with_front' => true ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
        'menu_position' => 14,
        'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt', 'editor','thumbnail') //here you can specify what type of inputs will be accessible in the admin area
      );

    register_post_type( 'spec-needs-res' , $args );
}
```

Comment: Hmm... How does your register_post_type Look?

Comment: I just added my custom post type's code to the answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template_search_spec_needs.php, remove the custom query. The parameters in your url (s=&post_type=spec-needs-res) should work with the "normal" loop just fine.

So try changing your template_search_spec_needs.php to something like this:

```
<?php

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  ?>

        <div class="span4 spec-needs-list-single">
            <div class="spec-needs-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <div class="plus-btn-spec-needs-cont"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="plus-btn-spec-needs">+</button></a></div>
        </div>

  <?php
    endwhile;
```

And you should be just fine ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me, I've tried using the simple loop but now it doesn't even seem to give me results when I do a research with an empty query. I've used the same template for the default search for the default posts (template_search_default.php) and it seems to work properly. But for the for the custom template, it doesn't seem to pick up the custom post type because I always get 0 results. Any Idea?

Comment: Not quite Sure, as i am in mobile right now. You could try and change the Post Type identificator to use underscores instead of minus. Else i have to try to Help tomorrow when i'm Back at Work...

Comment: Ok, I'll try with that one in that in the meantime, thanks again!

Comment: Just noticed that Relevanssi plugin was used and obviously created a conflict with WP search. Just deactivated it and seems to work properly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, is there a way to print more than one custom post type? I want to print these custom post type: catalogues-res, forms-res and spec_needs_res. With the code above I'm able to print just spec_needs_res. Any Idea?

Comment: You can try and do it by seperating the post types by commas like this: http://www.matrix-test.com/edtech3/?s=webinar&post_type=spec-needs-res,catalogues-res,forms-res . Apart from that, you could look into the pre_get_posts action (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)